# Trying to build a stream class that has something like iostream::endl

Tags: c++, operators

Am attempting to define operator<< in a class.  It is to take a manipulator.  endl is a manipulator of iostream.  My manipulator is my_endl.

The details of my_endl are important at the moment, so I left them out.

```
class FStream {

public:
    FStream();
    ~FStream();
};


FStream::FStream() {
}


FStream::~FStream() {
}



class DerivedFStream : FStream {
public:
    DerivedFStream();
    ~DerivedFStream();
    static DerivedFStream& my_endl(DerivedFStream& dfs);
};


DerivedFStream::DerivedFStream() : FStream() {
}


DerivedFStream::~DerivedFStream() {
}

DerivedFStream& DerivedFStream::my_endl(DerivedFStream& dfs) {

return dfs;
};

int main() {
    DerivedFStream f = DerivedFStream();
    DerivedFStream& rf = f;

    rf << DerivedFStream::my_endl;

    return 0;
};
```

When compiling I get

```
DerivedStream.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
DerivedStream.cpp:43:8: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘DerivedFStream’ and ‘DerivedFStream&(DerivedFStream&)’)
     rf << DerivedFStream::my_endl;
        ^
```

The impression that I am getting from the error message in that is considers the variable 'rf' to be 'DerivedFStream' instead of 'DerivedFStream&'.

Recommendations please...

Comment: You didn't implement any `operator<<`

Comment: You don't need to define any constructors/destructors here, you can just use the compiler generated ones. They are only adding irrelevant code to your question.

Comment: What is your declaration of the operator? References are automatically dereferenced/referenced, so using a reference as an argument should work for both a function that takes something by value and a function that takes something by reference.